# Python :-extracting names of the images embedded inside a pdf

Tags: python

I have a pdf document containing several images. I want to retrieve the names of these images.

I know that ExtractImages extracts images from PDF. I feel that this will somewhere have the functionality to fetch the name of the image.

How to achieve this using python

Comment: If you are looking for the original file names, then no, those are not present in the PDF.  When you use an image extraction tool, they just invent names like "image001" and "image002".

Comment: I don't think images inside PDFs have names. They are just generic objects stored at a certain location.

Comment: See example 1-8 [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/developing-with-pdf/9781449327903/ch01.html) for more info.